# What happens if the server closes the socket first?

Tags: linux, sockets, unix, network-programming

Here is the situation: I have 2 machines, A and B. A listens to a port p. B creates a socket s1 and connects to p. A accepts the connection in socket s2. For now, A and B can communicate with each other through the socket.

However, if I kill the program in A and then restart this program some time later, B doesn't know because it hasn't sent any data to A during this period. Now B begins to write data to A through s1. What will happen next? Why?

Actually I found the `write` call did not fail but A still didn't get the data. What's more, if I put s1 in epoll device, I found the event returned by `epoll_wait` is `EPOLLERR | EPOLLHUP` after the call to `write`. Why?

Unfortunately, under this situation, it seems to lose the data since the `write' call didn't fail but A couldn't get the data. Any solutions?

Comment: B should get `EPIPE` for failed `write`. How do you know `write` didn't fail? Some sample code + output will be helpful.

Comment: In general, you can't rely on the lack of an error on a write to indicate that data has been transmitted.  You need to check for errors on close.  This is true of writing to disk as well as to a socket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. When you kill a program having established sockets, it will send RST to all other end. so B should receive RST on s1, and all future call on s1 will return error. But some firewall may filter out the RST packet, you can check the RST packet with tcpdump.
2. If B doesn't receive the RST packet in step1, when it continues sending other packets (write) to A, A will reply with RST packet, and all future call on B will return error once B receive this RST.
3. If B doesn't receive the RST packet in step2 too, after a certain time (write timeout), B will drop the connection, and all future call on B will return error.

You can see, write call seldom return error, it returns success if the packet is send, doesn't care whether the remote end receives the packet.

in your situation, you don't get EPOLLHUP as soon as you call epoll_wait, but after received RST or write timeout

Comment: Thanks, in fact B did not try to receive any packet from A since it played a role of `sending module`. In this situation, I can't rely on `write` to ensure data transmitting

Answer (score 2):

If the other end of a socket has been closed, it's actually made readable, and a `read` (or `recv`) call will return zero indicating that the socket on the other end has been gracefully closed.

Comment: Thanks, I've put this socket into epoll device and wait for EPOLLIN. Then it immediately returns after the server closes itself.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote to a disconnected stream (even if your machine didn't know it was disconnected.   Since you say "accepts the connection", I assume you're setting up a TCP connection between two machines.)

If you were talking UDP, there's no Listen/Connect/Accept, and the data would be sent to whatever is listening at the addr/port.  But you're not talking UDP. [edit to spell out the conclusion:] You're writing data into a dead connection (and at some point it will be clear the connection is dead, now that you've tried to use it).  Writing data doesn't tell you if the other side has received the data, success tells you it has queued the data to send.